# constexpr optimization error in gcc6.x?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, c++14, language-lawyer

I had in my C++11 library a `constexpr` function that sums the characters in a string. I then tried to update that function to a more natural style in C++14, and ran into a problem:

```
constexpr long sumchars11(const char s[], int pos = 0){
    return 0 + (s[pos] ? (s[pos] + sumchars11(s, pos+1)) : 0);
}

constexpr long sumchars14(const char s[]){
    int pos = 0;
    long sum = 0;
    while(s[pos]) {
        sum += s[pos++];
    }
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    static_assert(sumchars11("1235") == 203, "!"); // ok
    static_assert(sumchars14("1235") == 203, "!"); // error on gcc 6.x
                                                   // ok on clang
}
```

If I change the body of `sumchars14` from:

```
sum += s[pos++];
```

to the seemingly equivalent:

```
sum += s[pos];
++pos;
```

The `static_assert` no longer triggers. What gives? Can I not use post-increment in `constexpr` functions?

Comment: This look like a compiler bug to me.

Comment: I think so as well, but before submitting it I thought some additional pairs of eyes would be helpful - you never know when you're having one of those "doh!!!" moments!

Comment: This is not complicated. `sum += s[pos++];` is logically equivalent to `sum += s[pos]; ++pos;`, and there is no sequencing ambiguity. Time to wrap it up. Time to file a bugzilla bug.

Comment: As I said, I thought it was a bug. It never hurts to have a second opinion before filing a report - filing one now.

Comment: It would be clearer if your question just had the code that is NOT working, as a MCVE. It's confusing to post some code that works and say "change this, that and the other and it doesn't work on compiler X"

Answer (score 1):

As you expected, the function you have is perfectly fine. There are no rules for `constexpr` in C++14 that would disallow the specific form you chose, but allowing all the various logically equivalent versions you tried and found success with.

This is [gcc bug 77553](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=77553), and was resolved in gcc 6.3.